# VB Excel Search

Tags: excel, vba

Just want to ask, if MySQL have the function LIKE % to search for word, than what do VB excel have? I need to implement this on VB excel to search for keyword

Comment: VBA has a `Like` operator to match a string pattern. You can check it out in the Help section of the VB editor

Comment: You made "help" your username?!

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: on the plus side it's not 'help????????????'

Answer (score 2):

> *expression*.Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
>
> *expression*: A variable that represents a Range object.

[Use Excel VBA language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178845%28office.12%29.aspx)